# Getting arguments from created object

Tags: java

I got a obstacle class and there i got this:

```
 public Obstacle(final String name, final String action, final Position position) {
            this.name = name;
            this.action = action;
            this.position = position;
    }
```

In my main class i define an obstacle;

```
 Obstacle trapdoor= new Obstacle("Trapdoor","Open",new Position(3097,3468,0)) ;
```

How do i retrieve the position from that obstacle? Or more in general how do i get one of those arguments?

Comment: I would recommend working through a Java tutorial, like the one provided by Oracle: [Lesson: Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `getter` method, for example :

```
public Position getPosition()
{
    return this.position;
}
```

In the main class

```
Obstacle trapdoor= new Obstacle("Trapdoor","Open",new Position(3097,3468,0));
Position pos = trapdoor.getPosition();
```

Answer (score 0):

You define a method `getPosition` in the `Obstacle` class that returns the position. It is called a getter.

You get the position with `trapdoor.getPosition()`.

And you do the same for any member of the class that should be accessible to users of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
   public Obstacle(final String name, final String action, final Position position) {
        this.name = name;
        this.action = action;
        this.position = position;

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    ...
}
```

In your code:

```
   Obstacle trapdoor= new Obstacle("Trapdoor","Open",new Position(3097,3468,0)) ;
   String valueName = trapdoor.getName();
```